# How to run silently run ASP.NET MVC app as a background service started by desktop WPF app

Tags: .net, wpf

I have 2 web apps:

- UI in React JS
- API using ASP.NET Core MVC

They work fine when hosted on IIS, but I need them working on a local computer as a part of the standalone desktop app that doesn't have access to the internet. React app will be pre-compiled as HTML and displayed in a WebView2 component. As about starting servers, I thought that I could call `CreateHostBuilder` from WPF, but decided to ask for recommended approach in this case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services

**The question**

How to

- Start UI server
- Start API server
- Start WPF and point WebView / Browser control to UI server

Bonus point, if these servers will not be available from a regular web browser installed on this computer, only from WPF WebView.

Comment: Sounds like you need Electron to me.

Comment: The ASP.NET Core app is actually a console app that you can launch as a hidden process in the background, and via `--urls` switch you can ask it to listen to a local port, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration